# Ubuntu 14.10 minimal: jwm and startx

Tags: xorg

In VirtualBox I've installed Ubuntu 14.10 from a minimal image (no extra packages) and Xorg/jwm. I was getting ready to configure my .xinitrc when I tried "startx" to verify Xorg was installed and somehow, jwm started. I have no ~/.xinitrc and the default xinitrc doesn't have anything relating to jwm.

Maybe I am missing something obvious - how is jwm starting via startx when all I've done is installed Xorg/jwm via apt?

Answer (score 0):

Startx will start your default window manager. It looks like JWM is the only one, so it will start it automatically by default

Comment: In the past I remember always having to configure an ~/.xinitrc file before startx would do anything aside from start a blank X session. How is startx finding jwm?

Comment: when you installed jwm, it probably told X that it is the only one, and to use it.