# Ubuntu without Desktop Environment?

Tags: desktop-environments

I have an old, slow netbook.
I love Ubuntu and also Ubuntu has good repositories.

Is there any version of Ubuntu without a desktop environment?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server Took me a whole of 2 seconds to find with google using "Ubuntu without Desktop Environment" as arguments...

Comment: Try the server version, or Lubuntu (if you want to try out a light-weighted desktop)

Comment: thanks in advance... but plz tell me some more info about the Ubuntu server, comparing with Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: You will be booted into the Command Line Interface and have to control your system via this.

Comment: ohh, can i install a lightweight DE on it? such as Openbox?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox (just google "ubuntu with openbox" ;-) --- and if you want to really go lightweight you can even have `fvwm2`... http://askubuntu.com/a/519164/16395

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/602575/ubuntu-14-10-minimal-jwm-and-startx?rq=1

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openbox` or you could go with icewm or something else

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install the Server version of Ubuntu, it is not necessary as the difference between the server and desktop versions is primarily in the package selection, they are not different OSes.

I would recommend just disabling the X server on boot instead.

Comment: While your answer is correct , i would suggest you improve it by providing the step by step procedure on disabling X server. Keep up good work and welcome to AskUbuntu